# Is it possible to completely turn off the TaskBar in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, desktop

I've been using Windows 8 for about 2 weeks now. I have found that, on Windows 8, the task bar really seems to get in my way. I have set it to auto-hide, however, I still find myself drawn to it to do some things rather than using the more efficient Windows 8 way. As an example, checking the time. Rather than hitting Win + C (charms menu) which brings up the clock, I take my hands off the keyboard, grab the mouse, drag it down to the bottom of the screen, and wait for it to pop up.

Is it possible to completely disable the TaskBar in Windows 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I could find related is a 3rd party program, [Taskbar Eliminator](http://www.aviassin.com/taskbareliminator). (I didn't really want to dig through registry settings)

I did test that it works on W8, at first it hides it - but then it fully disappeared for me.

Comment: That works quite well. Thanks for the link. I was hoping there was an option built into Windows 8 (that didn't involve the registry). This will definitely work, though.

Comment: @krftsman -If I stumble on any better solutions I'll be sure to post back. It would be nice if they had.